# Is there a way to get a text percentage for battery capacity?

Tags: functionality

On other phones I have had, I could get information with respect to the battery drain, like "45% capacity" (as opposed to the visual representation of a two-tone battery). Is that information available on Windows Phone 7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I really don't know if I understand but did you mean "Setting"->"Battery Saver" where you can see "battery info"?

Comment: Yeah, that works! Thanks. But I would prefer being able to double-tap the battery icon to get the info.

Comment: I don't think windows OS allows third party apps to fiddle with top notifications. Applications are just allowed to use live tile notifications. So may be you can look for an app that works In that manner and show you the battery info on tile

Comment: I don't believe the current battery capacity is made available to app developers...

Answer (score 2):

I use [Battery Level](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/battery-level-for-wp8/69c5134c-5de7-426e-8ee1-d8442026d512). It has a live tile that shows your % all the time, and can show on the lock screen if you want. If you tap the tile you get a graph of your battery level over the previous day. You can also get it to tell you the battery level aloud if you want.

On my WP 7.5 I have to go into settings, scroll down to battery, and look at the tiny print. I definitely prefer having the live tile with a text percentage on my WP8.

Answer (score 0):

There is an app for WP8 called **Flashlight-X** that will show remaining battery percentage. I pinned it to my start screen (live tile). I hit it & the flashlight turns on via the camera's LED. It also shows battery percentage left.